# Split string at an uppercase character

Tags: php, mysql, split, phpmyadmin

My database contains full names, for example :

> VernonClemans
>
> SusanPostell
>
> RonaldGutkowski

without any space or delimiter. I want to split them into first and last name

All full names have the same format: 1 word with 2 uppercase letters.

How can I split them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pre>
<?php
  $string = "VernonClemans\nSusanPostell\nRonaldGutkowski";
  foreach(explode("\n", $string) as $name) {
   list($first_name, $last_name) = preg_split('/(?<=\\w)(?=[A-Z])/', $name);
   print "First Name: $first_name \nLast Name: $last_name\n";
  }
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: thanks,it's what i am being looking for

Comment: fine :-) And.. why do you not accept my answer?